# R KNN imputation - function returning erroneous results & missing help page

Tags: r, knn

I'm trying to impute some missing values in `R` using `library(imputation)` and `kNNImpute()`. The input data frame is 44 rows of 13 variables. There are 30 complete observations and 14 observations with missing values in 2 columns.

The code is saying it's imputing all the missing values; however, it's imputing the last 4 values as `0`. From my reading of the code, this appears to be a flaw based on using `0` as a default for errors. My code:

```
# impute data
library(imputation)
knn_data <- kNNImpute(x, k= 5)

# examine kNNImpute code
kNNImpute
```

`kNNImpute`'s code: See lines 4, 8 the function starting on line 24 and the 2nd line from the bottom (line 48):

```
[4]  prelim = impute.prelim(x)
[8]  x.missing = prelim$x.missing
[24] x.missing.imputed = t(apply(x.missing, 1, function(i) {...}
[48] x[missing.matrix2] = 0
```

`??impute.prelim` returns no results (the help page is missing). So, I can't examine this code.

However, the program flow for `kNNImpute` appears to be

```
[4]  # run a (seemingly undefined) screening function
[8]  # pull in the missing rows for later imputation
[24] # run imputation function
[48] # based on line [4] output, impute all "error rows"  == 0
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or how to solve this problem?

**FYI**- I have emailed the package author a link to this page.

Comment: `impute.prelim` is perfectly well defined, it's just not exported. Try `imputation:::impute.prelim`. I agree, though, that setting all values not successfully imputed to 0 should at least be documented (which I don't see).

Comment: Try `Amelia` or other `mi` packages?

Comment: I also can't find the documentation for these two internal functions required for the function on line [24]: `pdist` (line 40) and `.dist.2dto1d` (line 36)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: I used code identical to the `kNNImpute()` function to impute the 4 improperly imputed values.

```
impute.fn <- function(scores, distances, raw_dist) {
  knn.values <- scores[c(as.integer(names(distances)))]
  knn.weights <- 1 - (distances / max(raw_dist))
  weighted.mean(knn.values, knn.weights)
}

# impute errors - rows 41-44 are improperly imputed 
  # rows 1-30 have non missing avlues
#---------------------------------------------------------
x.dist <- as.matrix(dist(x))
dist_41 <- x.dist[41, c(1:30)][order(x.dist[41, c(1:30)])]
...

# fix impute - column 1
x$ABC[41] <- impute.fn(x$ABC, dist_41[1:5], dist_41)
...
```

An appropriate answer from the package author (or other) would still be appreciated.

**Note:** I have re-written the `imputation` package for wKNN. Improved package can be found here: [imputaton](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation)