# NAs introduced by coercion knn

Tags: r, na, knn

Getting the following NAs introduced by coercion error when running the following code:

```
install.packages("class")
library("class")

mydata <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", sep=",", header=FALSE)

mydata <- na.omit(mydata)

index <- 1:nrow(mydata)
testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)/6))
testset <-mydata[testindex,]
trainset <- mydata[-testindex,]

kblah2 <- knn(train = trainset['V9'],  
         test=testset['V9'],     
         cl=as.factor(trainset[['V15']]) ,
         k=1, l=0, prob=F, use.all=T)
```

I'm not sure what to do here.

Thanks

Comment: `V9`, in both the training and testing set, is a single factor (with five levels: `Amer-Indian-Eskimo  Asian-Pac-Islander  Black  Other  White`). How could one perform k-nearest neighbor on a factor? Did you intend to do something else?

Comment: @RichardScriven I don't believe that's the problem here.

Comment: Probably not, but I though the warning might be coming from the `?` marks. It would be good to check the result after `na.omit()`

Comment: The problem is that your V9 column is of factor type. You need to convert that and the test set into numeric using `trainset$V9 <- as.numeric(trainset$V9) `. But as David mentioned you won't be able to run knn on just two columns because you will have too many ties. You need more columns and preferably a column that is not discrete.

Comment: You may find [my prior question and solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294603/r-knn-imputation-function-returning-erroneous-results-missing-help-page) on this helpful. Although I'm using `library(imputation)` ... just checked `imputation' was removed from CRAN

Comment: looking at the code `class::knn`, it appears the problem is likely traced to **line 25** of the code, which makes a call to **C** : `Z <- .C(VR_knn, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. In my case, it was because I imported the data from Excel and excel had put commas between numbers to denote thousands. eg: "200,000".